# getWildcardQuery method of MultiFieldQueryParser doesn't process boosts map as getFieldQuery does

Tags: java, lucene

It's not clear why it happens, i.e. why `getFieldQuery` does handle `boosts` map to add weights to the resulting Query but `getWildcardQuery` (and other kinds of get*Query) does not. And how to force it to do that?

This is a code of getWildcardQuery from lucene-queryparser:6.3.0.jar.

```
protected Query getWildcardQuery(String field, String termStr) throws ParseException {
    if (field != null) {
        return super.getWildcardQuery(field, termStr);
    } else {
        List<Query> clauses = new ArrayList();

        for(int i = 0; i < this.fields.length; ++i) {
            clauses.add(this.getWildcardQuery(this.fields[i], termStr));
        }

        return this.getMultiFieldQuery(clauses);
    }
}
```

And it returns a Query without handling `Map<String, Float> boosts` as it `getFieldQuery` does.

```
if (this.boosts != null) {
    Float boost = (Float)this.boosts.get(this.fields[i]);
    if (boost != null) {
        q = new BoostQuery((Query)q, boost.floatValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more context to your question with code sample. Its hard to understand your question.

Comment: OK, I decided to extend MultiFieldQueryParser and override getWildcardQuery with handling boosts.

Comment: This was a [bug](https://github.com/apache/lucene/issues/8966) and will be fixed in Lucene 9.6.0

Answer (score 0):

They behave that way because of how they are used internally by the query parser. Note that both of those methods are `protected`, so callers of the parser, in general, are not going to have access to those methods at all. Unless you are creating a subclass of `MultiFieldQueryParser`, the only methods you will be calling are the constructor and `parse`.

---

Why there is a difference in the behavior of the two comes down to which parts of the query parser syntax they are handling. `getFieldQuery` is handling "fieldname:...". That is, it handles what is done with the field specification, and the rest of the query will then be handled by other calls. If `getWildardQuery` also applied field boosts, you would end up with those boosts being applied twice.

Again, though, that's only important if you are implementing a subclass of the query parser, it is totally irrelevant if you are just using MultiFieldQueryParser.

Comment: yes, I still call only constructor and parse but I've overrided `protected getWildcardQuery` so now it handle boosts as well. The result is what I needed, i.e. I call MultiFieldQueryParserCustom constructor passing there boosts as third argument, then I can parse wildcard queries and get results with weights.

Comment: Also I didn't get your idea how would boosts be applied twice? There are no other calls in `getWildcardQuery` besides recursive calls and final `getMultiFieldQuery`.